# Get the category name outside of the loop in category.php

Tags: functions, categories, codex

I am in a `category.php`, and I have to write the category name outside of the Loop. The category name needs to be pulled dynamically through PHP.

```
<p>You are browsing <?php get_the_category  ?> articles.</p>
```

I tried the above one, but it didn't work. Whats the fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `single_cat_title()`.

Comment: what it is it equivalent for a tag: single_cat_title();?

Comment: WP functions are generally quite consistently named, so for tags you'd want `single_tag_title()`. For generic terms you'd be looking for `single_term_title()`.

Answer (score -1):

I have to admit that I am not fully understanding your question.  Would you want to write a plugin with a widget to accomplish your task?
*What are you trying to do?

Usually I find that if I need to loop outside the loop, that I have to define which categories apply and which do not, usually for me another loop that is outside the Wordpress default loop.  I am working with an example of article loops and I hope to update this answer before it is fully complete.

For those voting - please wait until I have a complete answer available before voting.  I hope to take the updates to the question and update the answer accordingly.

Thank you for asking your question.

Comment: sir, please read the question it has all the requisite details. A simple one in deed.

Comment: slightly updated the questions.

Comment: I am using a custom-field and I need to similarly cycle among those on the particular wordpress page where the widget is located (using also the [widgets_on_pages] plugin to place my widget nicely centered on the page.  My current example is at:  http://www.shalomisrael.org/news/new-york-business-review/  I need to loop through the defined custom fields on each page.  Perhaps this is similar to what the question author is asking, so I appreciate additional detail.

Comment: It looks like you are spamming and trying to make backlinks. Please avoid spamming.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your full source so I can understand it?  I am not trying to back list links as I am working on this right now, and the question seems similar.  If you post a link on your web-hosting that would be appreciated, or even here!

Comment: What theme are you starting out with?  Are you starting with the standard starting theme (I remember Twenty-Sixteen) or something else that you are writing from scratch?

Comment: I have updated the plugin (similar concept) now available at http://shalomisrael.org/demo/carousel_edit_url_for_newspro_20171006.zip for download.  Look in the main carousel_edit_url_for_newspro/carousel_edit_url_for_newspro.php file;               echo '<p>Example for Business for the "'.$instance["category_name_textbox"].'" Category</p>';
       include "businesscarouselstatic/business_head.php";  /*content before the loop*/
       include "businesscarouselstatic/business_loop.php";  /*the loop*/
       include "businesscarouselstatic/business_tail.php";  /*content after the loop*/
....

Comment: My current strategy is to break up the code into the header, the loop, and the tail, using an example code segment that works fine (copied from a working page using the Code:Blocks editor to open the html file).